# Reading a .dat file in R from a UR

Tags: r, url, ftp

I've checked the resources you advised me to, however I found that:

```
 > setInternet2(NA)
 [1] TRUE
```

I run the following lines of code:

This works OK:

```
 x<-getURL("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-onemin/6406-2013/64060KFAT201312.dat", userpwd="ftp:my-email@gmail.com")
 b <- read.fwf("C:/Users/My_Name/Desktop/2015 Citrus/x.dat",    widths=c(10,19,6,9,18,6,9,8,10,2,3,2))
```

Manually saving the file, produces he same results:

```
 a <- read.fwf("C:/Users/My-Name/Desktop/2015 Citrus/64060KFAT201312.dat", widths=c(10,19,6,9,18,6,9,8,10,2,3,2))
```

However, when I try to combine getURL with read.fwf, I get error:

```
 b <- read.fwf(getURL("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-onemin/6406-2013/64060KFAT201312.dat", 
                 userpwd="ftp:my-email@gmail.com"), widths=c(10,19,6,9,18,6,9,8,10,2,3,2))
```

Why is this so?

Thank you

Comment: Did you make sure you include the "ftp://" at the beginning of your url?

Comment: Yes, I get: Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") : InternetOpenUrl failed: ''

Comment: and when I use the getURL method, the error I get is: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: closing unused connection 3 (ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/asos-onemin/6406-2013/64060KFAT201312.dat) 
2: In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file

Comment: Read about the  `internet2` parameter. (you don't say what OS you are on but I'm guessing one of the Windows.) If I'm wrong about needing to use that mechanism then please edit the question to include more of the needed information to investigate causes.

Comment: @BondedDust I edited the question again, now i really don't understand what is going on. I did check the internet2 parameter but now i don't understand the error i'm getting. Thanks

Comment: If you don't post the details of your setup and the full and exact error message, I'm not going to retract my close vote. I have found that using a browser to retrieve data to a local disk is much faster, so I question whether there is any advantage in solving your remaining question.

Comment: Not understanding an error isn't a good reason not to show it. In some (many?) cases, you can't directly read a file from an ftp site, you must download it. If you have 2 lines that work, be happy and don't worry about reducing your solution to 1 line.

Comment: Also the first argument to `read.fwf` needs to be a filename and `getURL(...)` is definitely not a file name.